# Should downvotes not be allowed after a time period, or add a "Vote As no longer an answer"?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I gave answered several questions in the past where the answer is now either out of date or invalid as technology has moved on. In this case the answer was correct and not is not correct and the answer gets downvotes, should there not be a time limit on this? Or add a feature where users can vote the answer as no longer an answer?

Comment: You can't update your answer?

Comment: You should either update your answer or delete it.

Comment: wow, immediate downvotes! in stackoverflow down votes are quote rare, I assume in other stack sites people download a lot? is this the case?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences): *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement*

Comment: @juergen d: fair enough, however is this not a valid question, given I am looking for an answer? an answer in this case explains the situation rather than a downvote (not assiming you downvoted).

Comment: I do update the answer... I was just asking a question..tough crowd :-)

Comment: @MarkRedman: Yes, it is a valid question. I disagree with your proposal and downvoted it to indicate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nah, not really. Votes are fine on answers as they stand. If they are no longer correct, downvoting them could be fair enough.

Now I get the idea. After all, the answer was given in good faith and might at one point have been correct. Developments just caught up with you. But you still have options:

- Update your answer. You can do so by adding onto it with an update, or by revising the original.
- Live with the occasional downvote. Your answer was originally correct, and might still be useful to those dealing with legacy code/technology. Just leave it as it is and move on
- Delete it. If there is really no point any more in having it around and you can't see the benefit of the first two options, you could consider just removing it if it's not the accepted answer. But that I would only do as a very last resort, if I would do it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answering the question. To Others: the downvotes don't answer the question, if people don't like the idea, fine, that is different to downvoting the question asked.

Comment: @MarkRedman for feature requests that's fair game on Meta. It's a yay or nay vote. It does not necessarily mean your question is a bad one. (Fwiw, I don't think it is).

Comment: Fair enough... So do I not delete this question in case someone else asks, or do I delete it?

Comment: You can't delete it.

Comment: ..or vote to delete it rather..

Comment: Why? Just leave it. You made a feature request, the response is not all that positive. Move on.

Answer (score 3):

If your answer is right once, you get reputation. It is okey for you. But why you complain when you get downvotes because your answer is no more true or satisfy the current condition?

Try to see it this way... You googled your problem and found an answer in Stack OVerflow. You try it but even it have some upvotes, it is not working. What do you do?  *Answer is simple*. You downvote and add a comment asking for an update.

Do not forget, all questions and answers in here is also a future reference for other users. And you have responsibility of your answers. If a such condition happens, you either *update* it, *delete* it or ask Question owner to *un-accept* it so some other answer may be accepted or question may receive more answers since it do not have a valid answer now.

You got your reputation because of your good and valid answers, and trying to keep it in exchange of dropping site quality is one of the worst things in here.

Comment: I am not complaining, just asking questions...